# How to maintain bookmarks in Visual Studio project for developer and team separately?

Tags: visual-studio, bookmarks

Where are the the bookmark details stored in a Visual Studio project?

project file : *.csproj 
solution file: *.sln

I am wondering if its possible to maintain bookmarks separately for team and per developer by default.

When I check the project into source control (Perforce) I do not want all my bookmarks to sync in for other developers but only a few which are useful to the whole team.

**Update #1:** we need some reference point in the code - that can be used as shorthand in email and commuincaiton between developers / support teams. For that we need to maintain bookmark at team level.

**Update #2:** It seems everyone suggested not to share bookmarks at team level (it's a hidden file for a reason etc...). I am wondering if there is any other tool in Visual Studio to meet the purpose here. The best thing about bookmarks is their ability to hyperlink to any portion of a code which is extremely useful if the code base is HUGE!

**>>** Closest answer by 'zainnab' (see below), but this option requires to modify (checkout) code files.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are checking in things other than source code and documentation to your source control system, anyway. Things like user settings, project files, binaries (unless they are external dependencies), and similar files should not, IMO, be checked into source control.

Comment: we need some refrence point in the code - that can be used as shothand in email and commuincaiton between developers/support teams. For that we need to maintain bookmark at team level.

Comment: What kinds of reference points are you sharing? If you are referring to particular functions, then naming the function in questions should be good enough. You might also want to consider using regions to help identify particular sections of code.

Comment: I can think of at least one great reason to do this. If I'm using GIT for version control. I'd LOVE to be able to check in MY bookmarks as they are for the current branch I'm working in. If I just leave the bookmarks as they are and switch branches, it's often the case that the bookmarks no longer point to the same code as before, which can be a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's suggested that you NOT use Bookmarks for team activities but instead use comment tokens (aka "TODO's", etc..) as they travel with the source code.

Comment: can we have a hyperlink to a particular line of code in ToDo ? 
we can in bookmarks and thats why they are more usefull.

Comment: ToDo comments show up in the task list and, by double clicking on them, they will go to the line of code they were set on.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: thanks, I have been searching for something like that for ages. I use this in Eclipse extensively, didnt find it in VS and built all those notes and todos manually with bookmarks. I also just encountered the same problem that I cannot or do not want to commit those bookmarks. You saved me a hell lot of work thanks for that!

Comment: Totally agree this is the best solution!!  I've been using standard bookmarks in a large project for a while and love them but they have two weakness - can drift about because they only refer to line numbers not actual places in the code, and they can't easily be shared between developers or even the same developer on different machines.  Quite big weaknesses when you think about it...

Comment: ... Go to Tools/Options/Environment/Task List and add a new tag to record your bookmarks.  I wanted to use the phrase 'MARK' but this word is too common, so I'm using 'BOOKMARK' set as low priority.

Whenever I want to leave a bookmark I just type "//BOOKMARK: this is a bookmark", and that's it done, simple!
To view them just open the Task List window and sort by priority or description and scroll down.

Answer (score 3):

Well shared bookmarks are extremely useful for code review at least.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks are stored in your solution's .SUO file.

However it is not a good idea to put this file into source control. That's why it's a hidden file.

In my opinion, bookmarks are user-specific and should not be shared between team members.

Comment: pls see my comments in update - as why we need to checkin bookmarks in source control.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks like index of code. So, it would be very useful for all team.
I don't need to think or search where is the code which does do that...
Just go to bookmark window and double click to categorized index.

[image]

Comment: Excellent observation. I just recently discovered that the bookmarks window supports this kind of organization. But unfortunately you can't really check those bookmarks into source control for use only by you. So the utility is limited.